# Emulator not running app. Even DDMS not showing emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have tried several times but my AVD is not ruuning the app.

Even the DDMS is not showing the AVD.

I've tried stopping & restarting AVd, but it didn't helped. (Pic attached, please zoom..sorry for resolution)

I'm running 64-bit win7 & in the task manager I can see adb.exe*32. Does this create nay problem?

Thank You[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your eclipse to point out android sdk location?. If not, configure it by selecting "Window->Preferences" and select "Android", and select your SDK location. Also you should have installed ADT plugin.

You can refer the following link

developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.htm

Comment: checked...no problem there